# After installing Manjaro, windows is not showing in boot menu

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, dual-boot, manjaro

I was dual booting Windows 10 and Linux Mint 17.3 Mate.
Everything was fine; I was able to dual boot.

Last night I decided to install Manjaro Linux and I did so.

After installing Manjaro, all I get in my boot menu is Manjaro. Windows is not there in the boot menu, so I can not boot into Windows 10 anymore.

Is there any way to get Windows 10 back in the boot menu?

Answer (score 2):

If it's BIOS rather than UEFI...

Install `os-prober` if it is not already. Then run `update-grub`. It should automatically detect the windows install and put it in `grub.cfg` so you can boot it.

If UEFI, I'm not sure why it should be different, but docs seem to imply it's relevant somehow.